# merge multiple worksheets into one worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have trouble in this one...

I want to merge multiple worksheets into one. but everytime I run this code it overwrites some of the data. It should just copy and paste all the data into one worksheet named "Combined"

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets.Add(Before:=Worksheets(1))
ws.Name = "Combined"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range
Set rng = Worksheets(2).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
rng.copy ws.Range("A1")

Dim i As Integer

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet, rngCopy As Range, rngDest As Range

For i = 3 To Worksheets.Count

    Set wsCopy = Worksheets(i)
    With wsCopy
        Set rngCopy = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Set rngCopy = rngCopy.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count - 1)
    End With

    With ws
        Set rngDest = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End With

    rngCopy.copy rngDest

Next i

' Delete original worksheets
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Combined" Then ws.Delete
Next ws
```

I have 3 worksheets. "Dept", "Saving", and "TimeDmnd" they all have the same header.

thank you.

Comment: *everytime I run this code it overwrites some of the data* I cannot reproduce this. As a recommendation - store/recalculate current last row number (and build the destination address) on the destination worksheet (by adding `rngCopy.Rows.Count` to it) instead of `Set rngDest` statement.

Comment: Is only one row being overwritten?

Comment: on Dept sheet I have 10 rows of data and on Saving sheet I have 25 rows and on the last sheet which is Timedmnd I have also 10 rows. And if I run the macro I only have 1 sheet that have only 25 rows Timedmnd overwrites 10 rows of Dept and Saving sheets data.. sorry I'am bad at english